# IllegalArgumentException: Can´t serialize class (even it implements Serializable)

Tags: java, mongodb, serialization, lombok, nosql

I successfully set up a MongoDB Database and my Java program is connecting to it fine. However, when I try to save an instance of this class, I get an error:

```
@Data
public class NormalUser extends User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1324235L;

    public NormalUser(final String name, final String surname, final String address,
                      final String dni, final Gender gender, final String bankAccount) {
        super(name, surname, address, dni, gender, bankAccount, Role.NORMAL_USER, false);
    }
}
```

(Please note I am using Lombok @Data annotation and that the class extends another class that uses the same annotation and only has the constructor and the attributes.)

The error I am getting is weird from my point of view, as long as it says the class can´t be serialized even it implements `Serializable`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class entities.users.NormalUser
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:270)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:174)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:120)
    at com.mongodb.DefaultDBEncoder.writeObject(DefaultDBEncoder.java:27)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(OutMessage.java:289)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:261)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:226)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:59)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:104)
    at repositories.UsersRepository.createUser(UsersRepository.java:35)
    at repositories.UsersRepository.main(UsersRepository.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the super class:

```
@Data
public abstract class User implements Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 12314362564783L;

    private String surname;
    private String address;
    private String dni;
    private Gender gender;
    private String bankAccount;
    private Role role;
    private boolean admin;
    private String name;

    public User(final String name, final String surname, final String address,
                final String dni, final Gender gender, final String bankAccount,
                final Role role, final boolean admin) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.address = address;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.bankAccount = bankAccount;
        this.role = role;
        this.admin = admin;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE #2**
Is this enough to serialize the **enum** `Gender`?

```
public enum Gender implements Serializable {

    MALE, FEMALE;
}
```

Comment: Is everything in your superclass serializable?

Comment: @Reimeus super class added, question updated

Comment: what about `gender` and `role` - are they serializable?

Comment: @Reimeus Good observation, they´re not. Should they?

Comment: Yes, all fields need to be either `transient` or `Serializable` in a `Serializable` class.

Comment: @Zircon Could you please add an example? I am trying to search on the internet ways to serialize then without success. I am updating the question with the enum gender. Thanks in advance

Comment: `enum`s are automatically `Serializable`. What about `Role`? Is it a class? Does it have fields of other classes in it as well?

Comment: @Zircon Thank you. Role is another enum as well as Gender, with two values, NORMAL and ADMIN. It hasn´t got any kind of class or field on it, as well as Gender

Comment: Everything looks right. Are you sure that your program is using your newest, saved version of each class? Make sure each class is saved, any deployments are republished, and any servers are restarted.

Comment: In this case "serialization" doesn't mean "java serialization", but a generic serialization, i.e. converting an object to some internal format. With mongo that internal format is BSON. It has nothing to do with `Serializable`.

Comment: @Roman Ok, thanks, but what is the actual problem then? I am trying to encapsulate NormalUser in a BasicDBObject, without success. How can I do it?